# ColdFusion Encrypting ID from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, coldfusion, mvc.jquery.datatables

All,

I am racking my brain trying to figure out how to intercept and encrypt database record ID from a JSON request using ColdFusion. Included below is my code, and my sorry attempt. Any help would be great.

```
<cfquery name="GetAppData" datasource="MYSQLSTUFF">
    SELECT *
     From MYDATATABLE
</cfquery>
<cfset myKey = "VpugAocKZVP8BZzamx52Yw=="/>
<cfset data = [] />
<cfoutput query="GetAppData">
<cfset EID = #EMPLOYEE_ID#/>
<cfset EMPLOYEE_ID = #Encrypt(EID,myKey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX')#/>
    <cfset obj = {
        "EMPLOYEE_ID" = EMPLOYEE_ID,
        "LAST_NAME" = LAST_NAME,
        "FIRST_NAME" = FIRST_NAME,
        "EVER_NUM" = EVER_NUM,
        "SortOrderDate" = SortOrderDate,
        "DOCS_VER" = DOCS_VER,
        "DOCS_WAIT" = DOCS_WAIT,
        "APP_STATUS" = APP_STATUS,
        "LOCATION_NAME" = LOCATION_NAME
     } />
    <cfset arrayAppend(data, obj) />
</cfoutput>


<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes">
    <cfoutput>
        {"data":
        #serializeJSON(data)#
        }
    </cfoutput>
</cfprocessingdirective>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No" showdebugoutput="No">
```

I am trying to use this encrypted id to use for a link to another page showing the details of the employee id.

Comment: I guess, I am placing the <cfset's in the wrong place or totally missing it all together.

Comment: You should write up your answer so that others can learn from it.

Comment: As soon as I can figure out how to do this I'll post an answer.

Comment: You didn't say what the code is actually doing (error, wrong result, etc... ) but I'd guess you're not getting the encrypted value? See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49223332/8895292) for details.

Comment: @EddieB Are your IDs integer?  If so, you could use the HashIDs library. http://hashids.org/ It's a small open-source library that generates short, unique, non-sequential ids from numbers.  (I've used this in some projects so that that IDs aren't sequential & guessable.)

Comment: Is there a EMPLOYEE_ID field in your query?  It might be ignoring your variable because the query variable with the same name is taking precedence.  Try giving EMPLOYEE_ID a scope, in every place it is used; example: variables.EMPLOYEE_ID.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice right away that @Ageax had already explained this very nicely in their answer.

Comment: Triva: knowing the scope precedence was often a question on the CF certification exam.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR;**

Take another look at [my sample code on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213809/8895292). It's caused by improper scoping. The solution is to properly scope all variables (or use a variable name that is not also one of the query column names).

```
<!--- use query scope to overwrite query column value --->
<cfset queryName.columnName[queryName.currentRow] = Encrypt(...)> 

<!--- OR use "variables" scope to reference new variable --->
<cfset variables.EMPLOYEE_ID = Encrypt(...)> 
...
<cfset obj = {
        "EMPLOYEE_ID" = variables.EMPLOYEE_ID,
        ....
     } />
```

**Explanation**

When you assign a variable without a scope, it's placed in the default scope `VARIABLES`. So this code isn't overwriting the query column value, it's creating a totally new variable in the `VARIABLES` scope.

```
<cfset EMPLOYEE_ID = Encrypt(EID,sampleKey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX')/>
```

... same as if you were to write this:

```
<cfset variables.EMPLOYEE_ID = Encrypt(EID,sampleKey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX')/>
```

**That inadvertently creates two "EMPLOYEE_ID" variables**, causing ambiguity when trying to *read* the value here:

```
<cfset obj = {
    "EMPLOYEE_ID" = EMPLOYEE_ID,
    ....
 } />
```

Because `EMPLOYEE_ID` isn't scoped, CF must guess which of the two variables you want - the one in the query or the `VARIABLES` scope. CF then searches for  `EMPLOYEE_ID` the various scopes:

> If you use a variable name without a scope prefix, ColdFusion checks the scopes in the following order to find the variable:
>
> 1. Local (function-local, UDFs and CFCs only)
> 2. Arguments
> 3. Thread local (inside threads only)
> 4. Query (not a true scope; variables in query loops)
> 5. Thread
> 6. Variables
> 7. CGI
> 8. ... etc...

Then [returns the one with the highest precedence](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html). Because you're inside a query loop, the "query" scope has the higher precedence. That's why you're getting the original un-encrypted value, instead of the encrypted one.

```
<!--- simulate query data --->
<cfset myKey = "VpugAocKZVP8BZzamx52Yw=="/>

<cfset GetAppData = queryNew("EMPLOYEE_ID","integer", [ {EMPLOYEE_ID=1}])>

<cfoutput query="GetAppData">
    <cfset EMPLOYEE_ID = Encrypt(EMPLOYEE_ID,myKey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX')/>

    (Unscoped) EMPLOYEE_ID = #EMPLOYEE_ID#<br>
    (Scoped) variables.EMPLOYEE_ID = #variables.EMPLOYEE_ID#<br>
    (Scoped) GetAppData.EMPLOYEE_ID = #GetAppData.EMPLOYEE_ID#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Question, since I have more than just employee_id in my response, now it errors out and says last_name is undefined. It appears that its only passing employee_id in the response.

Comment: The above is a simplified example to demonstrate why the original code doesn't work.  Keep all of the same keys your real code, just change the way you're creating EMPLOYEE_ID.

Answer (score 1):

So, after reading Ageax response over and over again and then having a moment of clarity, I realized how easy the solution was.

```
<cfoutput query="GetAppData">
    <cfset ED_ID = Encrypt(EMPLOYEE_ID,myKey,'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding','HEX')/>
    <cfset obj = {
        "EMPLOYEE_ID" = variables.ED_ID,
```

By catching EMPLOYEE_ID, then setting it to ED_ID I was able to accuratly define the proper item.

The following works perfectly. Thanks again to Ageax for the great advice.

Comment: Yep, though to avoid similar issues best to use the `variables` scope in the `cfset` statement as well. You could also just skip the extra variable entirely and do the assignment directly in the structure. `<cfset obj = { "EMPLOYEE_ID" = Encrypt(...), ... more keys } />`

Comment: Great advice, I'll add that to the code now, thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Glad it helped.  (Normally CF's flexibility is great, the "query scope" vs "variables scope" is one case where that flexibility can bite you ;-)